# Xcode 5 compilation

Tags: dll, xcode5

I've got a project which is going to be a c++ library for use in other c++ code.

It's made of a single .cpp implementation file and a single .h file for the interface. Normally I'd just compile the .cpp implementation file and then link it with other files with g++ in something like Ubuntu, however in Xcode 5 there's the Option Product>Build, Product>Build for... Running,testing, profiling and then there are the Perform action options to compile analyse, pre-process and assemble individual files. So with Xcode 5 how exactly do I complete my c++ library project in that I can then include it in other programs? And what happens when I use the options mentioned above like build and compile, because I see no new output files even though the build is successful - I'm guessing they go somewhere else I don't know about. I've googled this but I mostly find Xcode 4 stuff.

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: How do you want to provide the code?  Static library or dynamic library?

Comment: My understanding is a dynamic library is utilised at runtime and is good for big applications where you may want different functionally at different times - my library isn't that large so I think static is ok.